# custom settings in apex

Tags: customsetting

how can I get value of my custom settings `PrefixGroup__c` before insert record in Apex class.
This is my code but is not working.

```
Map<String, powerBI_authentication__c> setting = powerBI_authentication__c.getall();
system.debug('++setting' +setting);
powerBI_authentication__c PrefixGroup = setting.get('PrefixGroup__c');    
system.debug('++PrefixGroup' +PrefixGroup);
```

Comment: depending on the apex class version, results in the `setting` map may have key upper v lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Just make sure you have custom setting records in your org with name `PrefixGroup__c`. You can refer the screenshot to make it clear what I am talking about.

[image]

Note, You can directly access the records using these methods:-

```
powerBI_authentication__c myCS1 = powerBI_authentication__c.getValues('PrefixGroup__c');
powerBI_authentication__c myCS2 = powerBI_authentication__c.getInstance('PrefixGroup__c');
```

Refer:- [Custom Settings Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm)

Comment: off-topic - IMHO its best to mask customer org details :)